# strange layout behavior when iOS device placed on desk

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a fairly simple Xamarin forms layout.
The layout works as expected as long as I hold the iPhone, but when placed on a flat surface and I then navigate to a specific page the page, gets an incorrectly layout.

The offending page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:BaseContentPage  xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Mainapp.Pages" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:customcontrols="clr-namespace:Mainapp.CustomControls" xmlns:forum="clr-namespace:Mainapp.Pages.Forum" x:Class="Mainapp.Pages.Forum.ForumTopicDetailPage">
    <pages:BaseContentPage.MainContent>
        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" >
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <Grid  Padding="65,5,5,5" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="ContentGrid" BackgroundColor="Green">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label  x:Name="LblTopTitle" Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" MaxLines="2" />
                    <Label x:Name="LblAuthor" Style="{StaticResource SubTitleStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="None" FontSize="12"/>
                    <customcontrols:UserInitialsView VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="UserIntials"></customcontrols:UserInitialsView>

                </Grid>
                <ListView x:Name="TableListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  IsVisible="true"
                  SeparatorColor="Transparent"
                  SelectionMode="None"
              BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BlueBackground}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <forum:TopicCommentCell CommentContent="{Binding}" UserChangedLikeStateForComment="UserChangedLikedStateForContent"  />
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListView.Header>
                        <Grid Padding="0,0,0,10" BackgroundColor="Purple">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="36" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Light_Ivory}" Text=""/>
                            <Frame HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="36" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Light_Ivory}"  Grid.RowSpan="5" />
                            <Label Padding="10,0,10,0" x:Name="LblListTitle"  MaxLines="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Style="{StaticResource Topic_HeadlineStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Text="TITLE" />
                            <Label Padding="10,0,10,0" x:Name="LblListText"   VerticalOptions="Start" Style="{StaticResource Topic_TextStyle}"   LineHeight="1.5" Grid.Row="2"  Text="TEXT TEXT TEXT"/>
                            <customcontrols:LikeView Padding="10,20,0,0" x:Name="LikeView" Grid.Row="3" UserChangedLikedState="UserChangedLikedStateForContent"></customcontrols:LikeView>
                            <Label Padding="10,0,10,0" x:Name="LblCommentHeader" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  MaxLines="1" VerticalOptions="Start" Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}" Grid.Row="5" Text="Kommentarer" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ListView.Header>
                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <Label BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="100"/>
                    </ListView.Footer>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
             <customcontrols:FloatingTextEditor DidFinishWithDone="FloatingTextEditor_DidFinishWithDone" KeyboardDidShow="FloatingTextEditor_KeyboardDidShow" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1"></customcontrols:FloatingTextEditor>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </pages:BaseContentPage.MainContent>
</pages:BaseContentPage>
```

I'm not using the gyroscope and the app is set to Portrait mode only.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Expected layout, and what happens when i hold the Phone:
[image: 1]

Layout when phone is placed on a level plane:
[image: 2]

Comment: The issue seems caused by the AbsoluteLayout  . You could share  your sample to github so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: Hi Lucas, I can't share the code, and the minimum sample I produced does not behave like this. I replaced the absolut layout with a Grid layout, and that works. Thanks for pointing me in this direction. BUT why does the absolut layout behave like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the absolute layout with a grid layout. It works, but I'm still not sure why the absolute layout didn't work